# CSS/HTML & Browser Problems with Weebly-Exported Site

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm part of a professional-oriented undergraduate organization at Michigan State University that wishes to maintain its web presence on our university's server, in part because the `.edu` web address looks professional. However, we wish to allow various members of our organization to edit the website, which complicates the situation because not everyone in our organization has the programming skills for HTML/CSS (our university prevents all personal and group webspace from using server-side scripting).

One potential solution that I have discovered uses [Weebly's](http://www.weebly.com/) website generating service. There is a feature of Weebly located under `Settings > Archive/Un-publish` that allows one to download a `.zip` file of the site after having manipulated the site through Weebly's GUI. Such a solution would allow our members who do not have the knowhow to edit HTML/CSS to simply edit the website through Weebly, download it, and then upload it to our university's server.

The issue is the following: for whatever reason, after doing this, part of the website is not rendering correctly in certain browsers. In particular, in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome  (though *not* in Safari or Firefox) the two columns in the main content area of every page are vertically centered. This is most apparent on the our [constitution webpage](https://www.msu.edu/~qualms/constitution.html), as the relative length of the constitution leads to the "Meetings" sidebar being located very far down the page. You can compare this to the rendering of the same page on the [Weebly site](http://qualms.weebly.com/constitution.html), where the issue does not arise and the "Meetings" sidebar is at the top of the page, *regardless of the browser*.

Does anyone know why this might be the case and whether there is an easy fix? As noted at the outset, we wish to maintain the website on our university's servers for professional reasons, so maintaining the website on Weebly and redirecting the `.edu` address to the Weebly site is not an option.

Comment: Please provide code for an example demonstrating your problem - http://sscce.org/.  Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting **your** problem.

Comment: `.wsite-multicol-col` needs to be set to `vertical-align:top`, not sure why it's a table though. But Weebly is complete shit, never use Weebly!!! :)

Comment: Thanks @NickR, that did the trick. If you want to put it as an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept it. 

And yes, I'm not too happy about having to use Weebly, but if you have any alternative suggestions that would allow people with no HTML/CSS knowledge to edit our website, I'm open to other ideas. It was the best I could come up with, especially with our university's ban on server-side scripting, which makes things like WordPress a non-option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `td` item in the table: `.wsite-multicol-col` needs to be set to `vertical-align:top`. To be vertically aligned to the top of the table.

In the old days, way back when...you could do `<td valign="top">`, in the markup -  but that's no longer valid, and we can control the styling purely through the `.css` file.